# Python sqlite3: how to insert data with missing key/value?

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to add new data entries, in the json format, into a database using sqlite3. 
The example database 'test.db' has a table 'cars' that takes 3 values, 'MAKE', 'MODEL' and 'COST'. 
The new data contains entries with missing name/value pairs:

```
entries = {
  "CARS":[
 {
    "MAKE": "VW",
    "MODEL":"Passat",
    "COST":23000
 },
 {
    "MAKE":"Honda",
    "MODEL":"Civic"
 }
]
}
```

To get around the KeyError raising, I used setdefault() and added key/None pairs if they are missing in each entry:

```
import sqlite3

keys = ["MAKE", "MODEL", "COST"]
with sqlite3.connect("test.db") as conn:
    c = conn.cursor()

    for car in entries['CARS']:
        for key in keys:
            car.setdefault(key, None)
        c.execute('INSERT INTO cars VALUES(?,?,?)', (car['MAKE'],   car['MODEL'], car['COST']))
```

Although this seems to work, is there also a way to add entries with missing name/value pairs by using the SQL syntax?

Comment: you could also use `collections.defaultdict(lambda : None)`

Comment: Instead of `.setdefault()`, how about `c.execute("...", (car.get("MAKE"), car.get("MODEL", car.get("COST")))`. Since `dict.get` returns `None` if the key isn't found, this should do just what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use parameter binding, you have to supply as many arguments as there are parameters in the string. It isn't a question of SQL syntax, it is an issue of parameter binding syntax. I don't see any way around that.

You could use a combination of `collections.defaultdict()` and *named* parameter binding to make the code a little more readable:

```
import sqlite3
from collections import defaultdict

keys = ["MAKE", "MODEL", "COST"]
with sqlite3.connect(":memory:") as conn:
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("create table cars (make, model, cost)")

    for car in entries['CARS']:
        car = defaultdict(lambda: None, car)
        c.execute('INSERT INTO cars VALUES(:MAKE,:MODEL,:COST)', car)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to alter the column in your table to have a default value incase you don't supply it with an entry.

```
# Connecting to the database file
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
c = conn.cursor()
```

Adding a new column with a default row value

```
c.execute("ALTER TABLE {tn} ADD COLUMN '{cn}' {ct} DEFAULT '{df}'"\
        .format(tn=table_name, cn=new_column2, ct=column_type, df=default_val))
```

There are 3 ways of inserting data into an SQL table:

- With the "VALUES" keyword: creates one or more new rows in an existing table.
- With the "SELECT" statement instead of a VALUES clause. A new entry is inserted into the table for each row of data returned by executing the SELECT statement.
- With DEFAULT VALUES. The INSERT ... DEFAULT VALUES statement inserts a single new row into the named table. Each column of the new row is populated with its default value, or with a NULL if no default value is specified as part of the column definition in the CREATE TABLE statement.

To understand how you can INSERT into a table and see more examples see [source](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)

Comment: Would this, or setting default values when creating the table, work only if the new entry at least contains all the value names?

Comment: I edited the answer, and added in more details about how insert works with (and without) default values in the query.